# Find the number of all specific substrings in a string

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, complexity

I would like to ask a code review  regarding a concrete exercise. Let's suppose I have to get the number of all specific substrings in a string.

We call something *specific* if any of these conditions are is true:

> - The string consists of similar characters. For example: "aaaaa"
> - The string consists of similar characters except the middle one, which can be anything. For example: "aabaa"

To do this, I first decided to get all combinations into a list. I did it in an O(n³) solution just with 2 basic `for` loops and using `substring()` ([see more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679746/time-complexity-of-javas-substring)), this way:

```
private static List<String> allCombinations(String s) {
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= s.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= s.length() - i; j++) {
            output.add(s.substring(j, j + i));
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Subsequently, I used this method to count how many of these are special:

```
static long substrCount(String s) {
    long res = 0L;
    List<String> output = allCombinations(s);
    for (String x : output) {
        if(isSpecial(x)){
            res++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

`isSpecial()` looks like this:

```
private static boolean isSpecial(String input) {
    Set<Character> occurrences = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        occurrences.add(input.charAt(i));
    }
    if (occurrences.size() > 2) {
        return false;
    }
    if (occurrences.size() == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    return input.length() % 2 == 1 && input.charAt(0) == input.charAt(input.length() - 1) && input.charAt(input.length() / 2) != input.charAt(0);
}
```

I've got 2 questions:

1. This is a practice exercise with provided tests, and most of the test cases failed due to time complexity problems. How could I reduce the time complexity of my solution?
2. If you could give me any general feedback what to improve in - based on my code - I would be really thankful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I believe you are confusing the terms "specific" and "special" in the description.

## Method `isSpecial`

- You could move the `if (occurrences.size() > 2)` statement into the for loop, because once you know that there are more than 2 different characters, there is no need to continue adding more characters to the `Set`. Then you can also initialize the `HashSet` to an initial size of `3`, because it never can grow larger than that.
- You don't need the part `input.charAt(0) == input.charAt(input.length() - 1)` in the final expression, because when the length is more than two and if there are exactly two different characters, it can never be 
  `false` when `input.charAt(input.length() / 2) != input.charAt(0)` is `true`.
- Finally I'd put `input.length` into a local variable. That will speed up the `for` loop by a tiny amount by avoiding the method call and it will make the final expression a bit shorter and thus better to read

```
private static boolean isSpecial(String input) {
    int len = input.length();
    Set<Character> occurrences = new HashSet<>(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        occurrences.add(input.charAt(i));
        if (occurrences.size() > 2) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (occurrences.size() == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    return len % 2 == 1 && input.charAt(len / 2) != input.charAt(0);
}
```

## Method `substrCount`

This method can be shorten significantly by using Java 8's Stream API:

```
static long substrCount(String s) {
   return allCombinations(s).stream().filter(ClassName::isSpecial).count();
}
```

*(`ClassName` is the name of the class `isSpecial`is in.)*